# How application choose which address will use for outcoming communication

Tags: linux-networking, rhel7

I have a proprietary Linux distribution based on RHEL 7 and am trying to deal with the following issue. The machine has one primary network interface with two IP addresses assigned. The first one is present all the time and is static, the second one is configured by VRRP protocol. All server application listens on the static IP but I noticed that when they send replies, they use the VRRP IP when it is set.

How does the application or system choose an IP address to reply on interfaces with multiple IP addresses assigned? Can I somehow enforce the default address to send responses?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a `src` option in the reply route, if you do `ip route`?

Comment: No, I haven't set any source option. But thank you a lot, I had no clue about this and it is exactly the answer I needed. I would like to ask if you know how Linux systems behave when the source option is omitted. What is the exact way how they choose the default source in this case?